# Using Page selected using routing in navigation

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and learning by example. I created a nav component that I am calling in my app.component using the selector  What I want to do is hide some list entries in my nav component depending on the page I am routing to. For example  The thing I can't get my mind around is how to set the variable 'showLogin' to true if I navigate to 'login' page by way of example. I am fairly certain that the nav component gets created even before the login component initiates. I do think services are the way to go? I am using Angular 7.

Comment: Can you please post your code too..!

Answer (score 0):

If you are routing to different pages which don't need login but needs a change of display items in nav bar then I don't think you need a service for this. Inject a `Router` in your nav-component and listen to the Router `NavigationEnd` events.

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Router is injected in the constructor and the variable name is _router
  this._router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    .subscribe(
        (data: NavigationEnd) => {
            // set your flag here depending on the url
            console.log(data.url)
        }
    );
}
```

If you are restricting items on the nav component based on a logged in state then you can use a service (which may be using localStorage or cookies) and with a simple property binding to the updated property of the service you can remove/add items in the nav component.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. I am also restricting items based on logged in state and got that working fine with a service and localStorage.  It is the first part I am struggling with and was now working through observables but your solution seems great. Will try it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: I've done the following: 
Added
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

Declared _router: Router;

but get following error "Cannot read property 'events' of undefined"

When I debug using Chrome and hover over _router I can see it is null. Any ideas?

Comment: @Daantjiekat You have to inject Router, something like: `constructor(private _router: Router) {}`

Answer (score 0):

I realised I had to declare the instance of the router as part of the constructor. The following thus works 100% thanks to xyz.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-menulist',
  templateUrl: './menulist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menulist.component.css']
})
export class MenulistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myservice: VariableService, private _router?: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(
          (data: NavigationEnd) => {
              // set your flag here depending on the url
              console.log(data.url)
          }
      );
  }
}
```